# Proportionality of a system of polynomials

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, systems-of-equations, coprime

I am currently reading Ivanovs „Easy as Pi?“ in fact, I am trying to understand a proof in this book. Following statement is to prove:

> For $n\geqslant 3$ the curve $x^n+y^n=1$ has no rational parametrization.

The proof goes by contradiction. For this we look at three relatively prime real polynomials $p(t),q(t),r(t)$, not all constant; so that

> $(\frac{p(t)}{r(t)})^n+ (\frac{q(t)}{r(t)})^n=1$

this is equivalent to:

> $p^n(t)+q^n(t)-r^n(t)=0$

by taking the derivative we derive:

> $p‘(t)p^{n-1}(t)+ q‘(t)q^{n-1}(t) \ +$ $r‘(t)r^{n-1}(t)=0  $

If we now look at the system:

> $p(t)x+q(t)y+r(t)z=0$
> $p‘(t)x+q‘(t)y+r‘(t)z=0$

We see $x= p^{n-1}(t),y= q^{n-1}(t),
 z= r^{n-1}(t)$ is a solution.

*Now comes the part, that I don‘t understand, from now I will write the functions without the argument*

Since every solution of this system is proportional to the triple,(which is also a solution):

> $(q‘r-qr‘,r‘p-rp‘,p’q-pq‘)$

We find relatively prime polynomials $f,g$, so that

> $p^{n-1}=\frac{f}{g}(q‘r-qr‘)$
> $q^{n-1}=\frac{f}{g}(r‘p-r‘p)$
> $r^{n-1}=\frac{f}{g}(p‘q-pq‘)$

**Why is every solution proportional to the triple?**

My inital thought was that, if you think about a linear system of equations, the solutions to it create a vector subspace. But this can‘t be the reason, since we have multiplication of polynomials.

Comment: If $(r,s,t)$ is proportional to $(u,v,w)$, then $r/u=s/v=t/w$. If all of $r,s,t,u,v,w$ are polynomials, then $r/u$ is a quotient $f/g$ of relatively prime polynomials, so $r=(f/g)u$, $s=(f/g)v$, and $t=(f/g)w$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I just noticed I worded my question really badly, I have rewritten it.

Comment: I don't understand the last sentence of the question. Polynomials can be added, and multiplied by scalars, and those operations satisfy the vector space axioms, so there can certainly be vector spaces whose elements are polynomials. That polynomials can also be multiplied has no bearing on the case. Anyway, you have two linear equations in the three unknowns $x,y,z$, and as the two equations are not simply multiples of each other, the system is guaranteed to have a one-dimensional vector space of solutions. So, any solution is a scalar multiple of any other solutions.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the fact, that the polynomial ring $\mathbb{R}[x]$ is a $\mathbb{R}$-vectorspace. But scalars are $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ and not polynomials $p\in\mathbb{R}[x]$. So if you look at vectorspace of solutions, it will be a sub-vectorspace $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}[x]$, then you still only have multiplication of scalars $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ defined, but not multiplication of polynomials.

Comment: Polynomials are polynomials, whether you are viewing them as elements of a vector space or not, and they don't stop being "multipliable" just because you choose to think of them as elements in a vector space.

Comment: Let's look at it one dimension down. Let $p,q$ be polynomials, consider the equation $p(t)x-q(t)y=0$. One solution is $(x,y)=(q(t),p(t))$. If $v(t)$ is an arbitrary polynomial, then another solution is $(x,y)=(v(t)q(t),v(t)p(t))$. And indeed every solution is of this form. It's not so different from saying the solutions of $2x-3y=0$ are the pairs $(x,y)=(3v,2v)$ with $v$ arbitrary.

Comment: Alright, this was my second idea, but I wasn‘t sure, if one could find such $f,g$. I guess the simplest argument for that is that they are both solutions. Thanks alot for the clarification!

Comment: Let me encourage you to write and post an answer to your question, if you feel you now understand the situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Answer is quite simple, just don‘t overcomplicate it.

Since,

> $(q‘r-qr‘,r‘p-rp‘,p’q-pq‘)$

solves the system, and

> $(p^{n-1},q^{n-1},r^{n-1})$

does aswell, we know that

> $p(q‘r-qr‘)+q(r‘p-rp‘)y+r(p’q-pq‘)z=0$
> $p‘(q‘r-qr‘)+q‘(r‘p-rp‘)y+r‘(p’q-pq‘)z=0$

and

> $p(p^{n-1})+q(q^{n-1})y+r(r^{n-1})z=0$

> $p‘(p^{n-1})+q‘(q^{n-1})y+r‘(r^{n-1})z=0$

Since for some arbitrary $s\in\mathbb{R}[x]$ the triple

> $(s(q‘r-qr‘),s(r‘p-rp‘),s(p’q-pq‘))=(s_1,s_2,s_3) $

also solves the system (multiply $s\neq0$ on both sides). We know for a fact that there are relatively prime $f,g\in\mathbb{R}[x]$, so that:

$(\frac{f}{g}(q‘r-qr‘),\frac{f}{g}(r‘p-rp‘), \frac{f}{g}(p’q-pq‘)) = (p^{n-1},q^{n-1},r^{n-1})$,

since both of them are solutions, this also works for every other solution.